# Graphql: skip a parameter if its type is string

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, graphql-js

I have a graphql query for Markdown files which requests the `title`, `author` and `coverImg` from the frontmatter of the Markdown.

Some Markdown files do not have a cover image, when there is no image, then it looks like the type of coverImg is String

I am using `gatsby-image` which uses `sharp` and I would like to descend into the children of the `coverImg` parameter, if the `coverImg` is an object and not a string

---

This is my query

```
query($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $path } }) {
        frontmatter {
            title
            author
            coverImg {
              childImageSharp {
                fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
                  src
                  srcSet
                  sizes
                  aspectRatio
                }
              }
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

If I try this I receive the error

```
There was an error in your GraphQL query:

Field "cover" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.

This can happen if you e.g. accidentally added { } to the field "cover". If you didn't expect "cover" to be of type "String" make sure that your input source and/or plugin is correct.
```

---

It looks like there's [graphql if statements](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#directives) but I don't know how to use these to conditionally branch to children. It would be great if I could just add something like

```
 coverImg @skip(if: coverImg is String) {
```

Comment: Normally the way I handle these is just to check that the image is there in the component itself: `if (frontmatter.coverImg.childImageSharp) <Img fluid={frontmatter.coverImg.childImageSharp.fluid} />`. Would this not work in your case?

Comment: Schema customization might help https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/18271

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Gatsby doesn't infer the schema of your data on a per-file basis, so once it infer a field as `String`, that field will always be of type `String`.

You can use the schema customization hook to tell Gatsby that the field `coverImg` is a file (as suggested by @ksav in the comment):

```js
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  actions.createTypes(`
    type MarkdownRemarkFrontmatter @infer {
      coverImg: File
    }

    type MarkdownRemark implements Node @infer {
      frontmatter: MarkdownRemarkFrontmatter
    }
  `)
}
```

Then you can check if `coverImg` exists.

```js
if (!coverImg) {
  // no image
} else if (coverImg.childImageSharp) {
  // has image
} else {
  // file is not an image
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused, where exactly do I put this code? I put it in my `gatsby-node.js` file but it didn't fix anything

Comment: yeah, it's supposed to be put in gatsby-node.js — it tells Gatsby that the field coverImg should always be either null, or an image file. I've just noticed a type name is wrong, so I've fixed that. If it doesn't work, it could be something else in your setup. A minimal reproducible example would go a long way in letting others help you.

Comment: So it helped the original error but I'm getting this now `warn You can't use childImageSharp together with undefined.undefined — use publicURL instead. The
childImageSharp portion of the query in this file will return null:`

Comment: I got my program working a different way that I didn't want to do. If I have some time I'll post a minimum reproducible example

Comment: I tried your solution for a different frontmatter image which ALWAYS has a value, and received the error `You can't use childImageSharp together with undefined.undefined — use publicURL instead. The childImageSharp portion of the query in this file
 will return null:` and also `TypeError: article.node.frontmatter.featuredImage.childImageSharp is null` where as if I keep all my code the same and just remove that customSchemaCustomization function from my `gatsby-node.js` then my website builds no problem

Comment: Hey there's a bounty now if you want to give this question a better look

Comment: That's cool @Sam! If you provide a minimal reproducible example I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

I *think* should be possible to do what you want using [graphql union types](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types). I've never used them on an object vs a string, but there should be a way to do it